# Why my React router only loads the default route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am learning page navigation in React application using react-router,

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rahul Shivsharan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

This is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router";

export default class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>Hello, React Router !!</div>
    }
}
```

This is Repos.js

```
import React from "react"

export default class Repos extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>Repos rendered !!!</div>
    }
}
```

This is About.js

```
import React from "react"

export default class About extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>About to be !!</div>
    }
}
```

This is index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter,Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";  
import App from "./modules/App";
import Repos from "./modules/Repos";
import About from "./modules/About";

ReactDOM.render(
    (<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>            
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/repos" component={Repos} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />       
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>),  document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "storage">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My First React Router App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

This is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    "entry" : "./index.js",
    "output" : {
        "filename" : "bundle.js",
        "publicPath" : ""
    },
    "module" : {
        "rules" : [{
            "test" : /\.js$/,
            "exclude" : /node_modules/,
            "loader" : "babel-loader",
            "query": {
                "presets": ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                "plugins": ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

My Question is when I start server using

```
npm start
```

And load 
    http://localhost:8081

In browser it loads
    Hello, React Router !!

When I do 
    http://localhost:8081/about

It shows,
    Cannot GET /about

Same with 
    http://locahost:8081/repos

It loads
    Cannot GET /repos

Why I am not able to load paths other than default ?

Please help me out, whether I am doing something wrong,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) so that the webpack-dev-server will serve the `index.html` file for all the routes that are currently giving a `404 Not Found` response.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: ""
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["@babel/react", "@babel/preset-env"],
          plugins: ["@babel/proposal-class-properties"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: But this doesnt solves my problem, I am still not able to render html written in About.js and Repos.js on url or /about and /repos

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem,

I just had to do some changes in my index.js, as follows,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter,Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";  
import App from "./modules/App";
import Repos from "./modules/Repos";
import About from "./modules/About";

ReactDOM.render(
    (<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>            
            <Route  exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route  exact path="/repos" component={Repos} />
            <Route  exact path="/about" component={About} />        
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>),  document.getElementById("app"));
```

Above you can see that I have added word "exact" in Route tag

Secondly as suggested by above answer by Thole I hand to add one extra configuration in webpack.config.js i.e. as follows,

```
"devServer": {
        "historyApiFallback": true
 }
```

Thats it, and now the above example works,

So now,

When I load 
    http://locahost:8080

I load's html returned in App.js

on 
    http://localhost:8080/about

it load's html returned in About.js and so on